# fatal error: asm/types.h: no such file or directory when cross-compiling kernel 3.16

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, cross-compiling, arm64

I have been trying to cross-compile the Linux Kernel 3.16, and I keep getting the error:

```
include/uapi/linux/types.h:4:23: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory  
# include <asm/types.h>
                        ^
```

I am using aarch64-linux-gnu-4.8 to cross-compile for arm64 architecture on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. The file asm/types.h doesn't exist in my kernel folder, and it's not supposed to be there, but I am not sure why the cross-compiler is trying to search for it. I also don't have any asm-generic folder inside my kernel folder.

Any pointers on how to solve this issue? If it's a cross-compiler version issue, which one should I use?

Comment: I installed that package and it didn't work for me